# How to encrypt Samsung SSD?

Tags: ssd, fde, opal, self-encrypting-drive, samsung-magician

I have an 860 pro SSD with windows installed on it. In the encryption section (**Samsung Magician**) it says ready to enable. Idk What does this mean. Is the encryption enabled now? Or there are extra steps to be done? am I supposed to erase the drive or something?  What should I do? Thank you for your advices

Answer (score 1):

Use [SEDutil](https://sedutil.com/) and refer to [detailed instructions](https://sedutil.com/#instructions). I can't provide you with exact steps since it depends on several things: what disk layout you want to have, what part of disk you want encrypted, whether you want to use Pre-Boot Authentication (PBA), whether you want to couple your SED with Bitlocker, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a manual for you here: https://semiconductor.samsung.com/resources/software-resources/Samsung_Magician_7_1_1_Installation_Guide.pdf

Encrypted Drive

> 1. Class 0, TCG Opal and Encrypted Drive cannot be enabled
>    simultaneously. Only one mode can be enabled at a time and all other
>    modes must be disabled.
> 2. Security mode (Class 0, TCG/Opal or Encrypted Drive) must be
>    disabled (unlocked) before removing and installing onto another PC.

In addition

> What is e-DRIVE, and how do I use it? [eDrive (available for 840 EVO
> and 850 PRO)]
>
> eDrvie linked with BitLocker software is a technology to improve the
> security performance of BitLocker, which is provided by the Microsoft
> Windows operating system.
>
> BitLocker uses software-handled encryption, but when it is linked with
> a storage device that supports eDrive, it can perform hardware-based
> encryption, thereby improving both security and performance while
> minimizing CPU usage.
>
> After installing an operating system on a storage device that supports
> eDrive, run BitLocker, which will automatically link What should I
> watch out for when using e-DRIVE?the two. Among Samsung SSD models,
> 840 EVO supports eDRIVE.
>
> [How to set up e-DRIVE]
>
> -You can convert e-Drive to “Ready to enable” by using Magician software. Then, the e-Drive is automatically enabled when a clean
> installation of an eDrive-compatible OS is performed.
>
> -When e-Drive is Enabled, you cannot use Magician to manually change the status to Disabled or Ready to enable. For more information,
> please contact customer service or your OS provider (Microsoft).

https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/faqs/03/

Magician
https://youtu.be/LvuNnHLfySs?t=629

BitLocker Windows 10
https://youtu.be/K4aU-P0qu9Y

Comment: Im not talking about this bitlocker bs. Samsung SSDs can be encrypted on a hardware level, thats what i mean

Comment: @PizzaPie Yes, Samsung SSDs have the built-in hardware encryption, but you need a software to manager the encryption and especially to enter the password at boot time so this encryption is not usable without a software like Bitlocker.

Comment: Ok so i did the bitlocker, first off, only the C drive was visible to encrypt and not the other local drives, why? Second, after i clicked next it asked for a reboot, and when i rebooted the system is gone now. I cant boot into windows as it says no bootable drives detected. My bootloader is saved in C. And i didnt even got asked to enter a password or something. What should i do?

Comment: @PizzaPie - Make sure you have Secure Boot enabled and are NOT attempting to boot to a MBR disk. Additionally, the quoted instructions, seem to suggest a clean install of Windows was going to be required.  “Then, the e-Drive is automatically enabled when a clean installation of an eDrive-compatible OS is performed.” - Without specific and detailed information about the steps you took to enable BitLocker, we clearly cannot help, especially if your current situation is only described in a comment

Comment: Ok i will do just that, but wdym by eDrive compatibility? Isnt it supposed to encrypt the entire ssd? Let's say i create several partitions, some of which are fat32, should i do the procedure foe all of them? Some drives may not even be supported by poor windows, like ext4, another question, you mentioned secure boot, why? Doesnt it work on MBR?

Comment: *Doesnt it work on MBR?* No, in practice is DOESN'T. Windows strictly requires GPT for UEFI mode and UEFI mode is the only one where Secure Boot exists as an option.

Comment: @PizzaPie Forget about BitLocker/eDrive. You don't have to use them for hardware SSD encryption.

Comment: @ﾤﾡ "Forget about BitLocker/eDrive. You don't have to use them for hardware SSD encryption." What is your solution ?

Comment: It's not "my solution". It is the encryption technology in question by itself. It is covered by TCG Opal 2.0 standard (TCG Storage Security Subsystem Class, to be more exact), which defines the management interface. Any compliant tool will do, for example [SEDutil](https://sedutil.com/).